# Difference between "Propagation.REQUIRED" e "Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a service class (named A) which has a method with `@Async` annotation. This method async from class A, calls another service class (named B) which has the annotation `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)`. This class B, calls another service (named C) which also has the very same annotation from class B. And, the class C, calls a method from a repository class.
These sequence is all triggered by a post endpoint with a request body.
Being said, I'm facing an intermittent issue that, sometimes I get the result as expected and sometimes I do not have any result (using exaclty the same request body).
Looking into application's logs, I could see that, when I get no result, the endpoint do not reach the repository class and apparently the thread "dies" in the class A (when the async method is called).
So, my main question is: if I change the type of Propagation from `REQUIRED` to `REQUIRES_NEW` in the classe C, it would solve my async problem?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: @GauravJeswani I'm still checking if there will any kind of impact, specially with performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REQUIRED means a transaction will be created before the method is invoked, other nested services with REQUIRED will join this transaction.

REQUIRES_NEW in a nested service will create another transaction which will be independent from the first transaction it (with req_new) could be committed even if the first transaction (req) will be rolled back.

I doubt that the transaction propagation is responsible for the described behaviour ( thread "dies"). I would check the thread pools used for async also that there all invocations run through a proxy.

Comment: Do you have any ideia what might cause the "death" of the thread?

Comment: @dcm50 I don't know your implementation, but would suggest using a test program with async calls  which do only write log messages, if everything works fine check step by step the differences to your actual implementation.